# "The next big thing" phrase

Tags: phrases, expressions, slang, formality

Is the phrase "The next big thing" considered a formal or a slang phrase?

Especially when communicating with a professional committee.

Comment: It's an idiom. I do not see any reason it could not be used in a committee.

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for your comment, but is this idiom formal?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by formal. It is a little playful. Perhaps you want "next high-profile development" or similar

Comment: It's a cliché. As so many next big things have been disappointments it may be used ironically. I wouldn't use it in a formal document because it's inviting scepticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X is the next big thing in mobile technology.

The phrase is oft used in headlines, news reports as well as trade magazines, especially for technology.

It may be used for other fields such as entertainment, for example, to refer to an upcoming star, but the usage is less common and a hence little unorthodox.

However, as far as the technical world goes, it is a perfectly acceptable buzz word and something that gives impetus to your presentation as well as makes it less stiff.

The only exception is if all committee members are stiff collared and in their seventies.